# Открытие модального окна с использованием query.params в Next.js

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js, next

При открытии модального окна, делающего запрос на бэк из данных полученных через query.params сайт крашится. Первая причина которая мне приходит в голову, это то, что next.js старается найти такую страницу, а её нет, есть только компонент

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше подробностей. Какой код у вас используется в модалке, что реализовано на бэке для обработки, какие ошибки в консоли и т.д.